# How to map an object by given key using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that looks something like this

```
{id: "2", name: "foo", price: "1"}
```

I want to transform this to the following

```
{2: {id: "2", name: "foo", price: "1"}}
```

I'm able to achieve this today if I wrap this object with a simple array like so thanks to the friendly keyBy method for array

```
_.keyBy([action.response], function(item) { return item.id; });
```

What I would prefer of course is the same result but without having to wrap this with an array first. Does transform/reduce or some other lodash v4 method provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly with a function:

```
function convert(obj) {
 var result = {}
 result[obj.id] = obj
 return result
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

Short solution based on [ES6 computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer): `{ [obj.id]: obj }`

Example:

```js
var obj = {id: "2", name: "foo", price: "1"}
var transformed = { [obj.id]: obj }
console.log(transformed)
```